# Get ranking of query when getting a single entry

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm working on a project where you like posts, where likes are stored in table `likes` with postId refering to the ID of the posts from table `$wpdb->posts` (wordpress). I need `totalLikes` and the `rank` latter being the ranking of the current post.

This works when getting all posts, but when I need a single post I get `rank` as 1, and not the correct ranking, because the query result only contains a single entry.

```
SELECT @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank, $wpdb->posts.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes l WHERE l.postId = $wpdb->posts.ID) as totalLikes
            FROM $wpdb->posts, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
            WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
            AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
            ORDER BY totalLikes DESC
```

What do I do to get the ranking while getting a single post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank, $wpdb->posts.*,
             (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes l WHERE l.postId = $wpdb->posts.ID) as totalLikes
      FROM $wpdb->posts CROSS JOIN (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
      WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
      ORDER BY totalLikes DESC
     ) t
WHERE <whatever condition you want>;
```

Note that this does have a performance implication, because the subquery is "materialized".  However, you already have to do a sort so this should add little additional overhead.

Comment: It works.. thanks. However, this has nothing to do with it, the outcome is rather different than what I'm used to. I get this: `object(stdClass)#228 (25) { ["rank"]=> string(1) "2" ...` ... do you know how I get the data `rank`?