# Rank POST's based on meta_value in wordpress [Example: "Ranked 3 out of 12 post"]

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ranking

All posts have a post meta_value called rating. How can I show the ranking of a certain post based on this meta_value like this: Ranked 3 out of 12 post. Sorting on meta_value is no problem but then all post have to be shown, is it possible to only show the post place in this ranking on a single post?

I sort a list of post this way in the WP_Query, can this method be used to retrieve only the ranking of 1 post?

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'meta_key' => 'rating'
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
Ranked <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rating', true);?> out of 12 post.
```

For the current post.

Comment: This will show something like this: "Ranked 7.6 out of 12 post" because it echo's the meta value it self. I want to show the actual ranking it has in the order: 8.8 7.7 7.6 5.4 3.5 then this post must be called "3" because it is the 3th highest post based on its meta_value.

Comment: Then you'll have to do a _select_ query with `$wpdb` [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) and save the rank number to update it again.

Comment: Similar question answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558371/get-ranking-of-query-when-getting-a-single-entry